# Who gets enters-the-battlefield abilities with Bribery?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When I have [Terastodon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerastodon%5d) in my library and an opponent puts it into play under his control using [Bribery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBribery%5d), who gets to destroy the three noncreature permanents, him or me?

Comment: See also the [rulings on Bribery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45279): 'You put the creature onto the battlefield, so you control it and any “enters the battlefield” abilities it has.'

Answer (score 3):

When your opponent puts your creature into play with Bribery, it acts just as if they played it themselves (or, perhaps, put it into play from their own library). It's their creature, and the fact that you happen to own the physical card itself doesn't matter, except for some effects that explicitly use the word "own" or "owner". Terastodon does not have any of those effects. So it's your opponent who gets to choose what permanents to target and whether to destroy them.

If Terastodon dies, though, it will come back to *your* graveyard, not your opponent's. Once a card leaves the battlefield, then it *does* matter who owns the actual card.

Comment: A very clear and comprehensive answer. Thank you for that !!

Comment: @Jacobel If you find an answer that satisfies your question, click on the check mark next to the answer to accept it. You can always come back and change the accepted answer if someone writes a better one.